# Convert n key value pairs within struct into rows using PySpark & Spark SQL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Example data as follows;

```
    "data": {
        "type": "properties",
        "collection": [
            {
                "objectId": 23,
                "category": "Things",
                "externalId": "e3e052f9-0156-11d5-9301-0000863f27ad-00000017",
                "properties": {
                    "parentKey1": {
                        "key1": "Text of some description",
                        "key2": "0.00",
                        "key3": "",
                        "key4": "None",
                        "key5": "",
                        "key6": "",
                    },
                    "parentKey2": {
                        "key1": "0",
                        "key2": "",
                        "key3": "",
                        "key4": "3Zu5Bv0LOHrPC10026FoUw"
                    },
                    "parentKey3": {
                        "key1": "8355711",
                        "key2": "No",
                        "key3": "Default",
                        "key4": "64",
                        "key5": "50"
                    },
                    "parentKey4": {
                        "key1": "Some description",
                        "key2": ""
                    }
                }
            }
          ]
    }
```

I'm trying to do some normalisation of the properties struct, converting each property and key value pair into rows dynamically. The properties can change per collection. I'm trying to accomplish this using Spark SQL, but I'd be interested in PySpark also.

The final result would be something along the lines of;

| property | attribute | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| parentKey1 | key1 | Text of some description |
| parentKey1 | key2 | 0.00 |
| parentKey1 | key3 |  |
| parentKey1 | key4 | None |
| parentKey1 | key5 |  |
| parentKey1 | key6 |  |
| parentKey2 | key1 | 0 |
| parentKey2 | key2 |  |

I've tried looking at maps but I have a struct data type. I think I could solve it using python but I'm looking for a nice & clean approach.